# How do I add multiple string.counts into a list? I'm trying to print the numbers out using tuples

Tags: python

```
dna_string = 'ATGCTTCAGAAAGGTCTTACG'

length = len(dna_string)
print("There are %d letters in this DNA string." % length)

print('Now here are the amounts for the letters "A", "C", "T", "G" in order.\n')

combien_a = dna_string.count('A')
combien_c = dna_string.count('C')
combien_t = dna_string.count('T')
combien_g = dna_string.count('G')

print(str(combien_a) + ' ' + str(combien_c) + ' ' + str(combien_g) + ' ' + str(combien_t))
```

Comment: `collections.Counter(dna_string)` gives you a dictionary of letters with their corresponding counts (key-value).

Comment: As an aside, a style tip: You don't need to declare the local variable `length`, you can do that in one line with [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html): `print(f"There are {len(dna_string)} letters in this DNA string.")` Code is cleaner and easier to read without being cluttered by unnecessary single-use temporary variables.

Comment: Also, *"add multiple string items"* is called concatenation. Strictly you don't want to add them into a list, you want to concatenate them into a string, which you print. And there aren't any tuples in your code, I don't understand why your title mentions that. I'd move the sentence about what you currently do from the title into the question body.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
dna_string = 'ATGCTTCAGAAAGGTCTTACG'

print(*[dna_string.count(a) for a in ['A','C','T','G']],sep=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add these to a list like:

```
combien = [dna_string.count(x) for x in ['A','C','T','G']]
```

Answer (score 0):

collections.Counter is useful for counting numbers.

```
from collections import Counter

dna_string = 'ATGCTTCAGAAAGGTCTTACG'
# Counter object works like a dictionary with element as key and count as value
combien = Counter(dna_string)
print(f"There are {len(dna_string)} letters in this DNA string.")
# you can convert the Counter to a list of (elem, count) tuples
print(list(combien.items())
```

Output:

```
There are 21 letters in this DNA string.
[('A', 6), ('T', 6), ('G', 5), ('C', 4)]
```

Elements are ordered from higher count to lower count in Counter, if you want another order for the result you may sort like this:

```
print(sorted(list(combien.items()), key=lambda x: ["A", "C", "T", "G"].index(x[0])))
```

Output:

```
[('A', 6), ('C', 4), ('T', 6), ('G', 5)]
```